# tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 10.x.x.x

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I want to configure Jenkins sever to execute commands into Kubernetes. I created token using:

```
kubectl create sa cicd

kubectl get sa,secret


cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cicd
spec:
  serviceAccount: cicd
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: cicd
EOF


kubectl exec cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo

kubectl create token cicd

kubectl create token cicd --duration=999999h

kubectl create clusterrole cicd --verb=get,list --resource=namespaces
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cicd --clusterrole=cicd --serviceaccount=default:cicd


cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: cicd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "cicd"
EOF


kubectl get sa,secret

kubectl describe secret cicd

kubectl describe sa cicd

kubectl get sa cicd -oyaml

kubectl get sa,secret
```

Test:

```
curl -k  https://10.0.0.x:6443/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer <.......>"
```

I copied this secrets file ~./kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <.....>
    server: https://10.0.0.x:6443
  name: cluster.local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster.local
    user: grafana
  name: grafana
current-context: grafana
users:
- name: grafana
  user:
    token: <.....>
```

Jenkins configuration:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        .......
        stage('helm deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'config_de']) {
                        ..........
                    }
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get error:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://x.x.x.x:6443/version": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 10.x.x.x, 10.x.x.x, 127.0.0.1, not x.x.x.x
```

Do you know how I have to configure the IP properly?

Comment: This is a local cluster ? i.e you have access to control plane node ?

Comment: It's a remote cluster. I want to access the control plane remotely

Comment: Looks like Kubernetes API server certificate does not include the IP address "x.x.x.x" in its SAN entries.. inside my control plane when I run `openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt  -noout -text` I can see `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:` contains a list the Alternative Names (ALT names) for IP addresses in the Kubernetes API server's TLS (Transport Layer Security) certificate

Comment: Can you propose some solution, please?

Comment: I honestly cannot suggest valid solutions, as many inputs missing, Do you have any idea the IP address "x.x.x.x" comes from where ?
Probably one of the solutions is to update the certificate used by the API server to include this IP address in the SAN entries.

Comment: You can I think run `openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.x:6443 -showcerts` it will show certificate as part of output save it in `test.crt` file then run this command `openssl x509 -in test.crt  -noout -text` it will have `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:` as output

Comment: hm... I don't see IPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first check the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) details of a certificate using OpenSSL:

```bash
openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.x:6443 -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | \
openssl x509 -text -noout | \
awk '/X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:/{flag=1; next} /X509v3/{flag=0} flag'
```

After you have identified the SAN details, choose one of the IP addresses or DNS names listed in the SAN to be used in Jenkins. Make sure to update the `kubeconfig` file or any other Kubernetes configuration in Jenkins to use this address. Specifically, the `server` URL in the `kubeconfig` file under the `clusters` section should match one of the addresses or DNS names in the SAN.

For example, if your SAN shows `DNS:kubernetes, DNS:kubernetes.default, IP Address:10.x.x.x, IP Address:127.0.0.1`, then your `kubeconfig` might look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <.....>
    server: https://10.x.x.x:6443  # That IP should match one from the SAN
  name: cluster.local
```

Update this file and make sure Jenkins uses this updated `kubeconfig` in its pipeline configuration.

---

```bash
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.* -f
kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 10.0.0.x \
     --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 10.233.0.x --apiserver-cert-extra-sans localhost
```

The solution of deleting the old certificate and creating a new one with `kubeadm` essentially replaces the Kubernetes API server's certificate with a new one that contains the additional Subject Alternative Names (SANs).

The command specifies these extra SANs with the `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans` flags. The new certificate will therefore be valid for connections originating from those IP addresses, in addition to any originally configured.

Once the new certificate is in place, update the `kubeconfig` file or any other Kubernetes configuration in Jenkins to match one of the addresses or DNS names in the new SAN list.

For example, your `kubeconfig` may look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <.....>
    server: https://10.0.0.x:6443  # That IP should match one from the new SAN
  name: cluster.local
```

Update this file and ensure that Jenkins uses this updated `kubeconfig` in its pipeline configuration.

Comment: As I stumbled upon this issue with a new `v1.29.1+k3s2` install I found a note that during the installation of the first master one can specify the `--tls-san` option and here i.e. provide additional endpoints that should be added to the certificate, i.e. `--tls-san 10.68.0.80,192.168.30.100` where the primer IP in this example is the internal IP used by kubernetes and the latter IP the one used by kube-vip to allow other masters to join the control-plane or etcd (I'm just playing with it in a homelab)

Comment: @RomanVottner Nice! Don't hesitate to edit the answer if you have a reference to that note.

Answer (score 3):

The solution:

Delete old certificate

```
rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.* -f
```

Create a new certificate

```
kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 10.0.0.x --apiserver-cert-extra-sans 10.233.0.x --apiserver-cert-extra-sans localhost
```